# simple hello world program gives issue in webpy

Tags: python, web.py

I am trying to use the webpy server and it works for the hello world if I try the same with the template it gives me this issue.

```
import web
render = web.template.render('templates/')

urls = (
    '/', 'index'
)

class index:
    def GET(self):
        name ='example'
        return render.index(name)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = web.application(urls, globals())
    app.run()
```

**`templates/index.html`:**

```
<em>Hello</em>, world!
$def with (name)

$if name:
    I just wanted to say <em>hello</em> to $name.
$else:
    <em>Hello</em>, world!
```

**Error**

```
<type 'exceptions.SyntaxError'> at /
invalid syntax Template traceback: File 'templates/index.html', line 8 None (index.html, line 8)

Python  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/web.py-0.37-py2.7.egg/web/template.py in compile_template, line 911
Web GET http://0.0.0.0:8080/
```

why am I getting this issue?

Comment: True please find the code here https://www.dropbox.com/s/h7qaf05ugfylql2/test.tar.gz

Comment: The file too has the same code which is above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must reorder your template file. The `$def` statement must come first:

```
$def with (name)
<em>Hello</em>, world!
```